# How to click links with the same name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to click all three of these (not at once, separately) using either Javascript or jQuery. I'm using a Python module that executes Javascript code and trying to make a complicated macro, more or less.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<div class="buttons">
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Save" id="edit-submit" name="op">
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Preview" id="edit-preview" name="op">
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Save and create another" id="edit-submit-again" name="op">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "*click all three of these (not at once, separately)*" exaclty? **What is your problem exactly?**

Comment: Remember guys, I want to select them all separately, and individually. The MOST important one is submit. If I could only select submit I would still be happy.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You want to click on one of the submit buttons and then you want to catch what button has been pressed?

Comment: I want to be able to click any of the three. But the most important is submit. The others are just like gravy on top of that. So if I could just be told how to click submit, that would be amazing.

Comment: No, I just want to have Javascript click the submit button. I don't care to be told what button I've pressed. I am writing a Python script that is executing Javascript and telling the browser what to do. All I want to do is click the submit button.

Comment: They are all "submit" buttons. Whic one do you want to press?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery's [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) will come in handy for you

```
$('#edit-submit,#edit-preview,#edit-submit-again').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can try this:

```
var elms=document.getElementsByName("op");
var lunghezza = elms.length;
for (i=0;i<lunghezza ;i++){
     elms[i].click();
};
```

if you want you can use jquery each();

```
$('input[name=op]').each(function(){
     $(this).click();
});
```

If you just want type = submit then do this:

```
var elms=document.getElementsByName("op");
var lunghezza = elms.length;
    for (i=0;i<lunghezza ;i++){
    if (elms[i].type="submit" ){
       elms[i].click()
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger click on all inputs

```
$("[name='op']").each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

If you want to select once at a time, just use their id preceded by a #. Example:

```
$("#edit-submit").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the submit button a kick:

```
$("element selection goes here").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
$('#edit-submit').click();
```

This will trigger the click event, but of course, a user click on the submit button itself will do that as well...

Comment: Yes, but I don't want a user clicking anything. Any time a user has to click, is a FAILURE for this. It is supposed to be an automatic posting system.

Comment: Ah, ok. This little biot of code will trigger the click automatically anyway.